# How can I set the draggin box mc 50px from the bottom

Tags: actionscript-3

I Have a mc called box.

All I want is when dragging up I want the bottom of box mc 50px from the bottom of the stage.

Now it's in the middle of the stage.

Here is my code.

```
var topY:int = stage.stageHeight - box.height;
var botY:int = 0;

box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
var constrainY:Rectangle = new Rectangle(box.x, topY ,0, box.y+ (box.height-stage.stageHeight)  );
var dragxy:String = "";
function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    dragxy = mouseX + "_" + mouseY;
    e.currentTarget.startDrag(false, constrainY);
}
function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "when dragging up"? Instead of "scrolling"?

Comment: Try changing `int` to `Number` for `var topY`.

Comment: Yes, when dragging up.

I've have change to >> var botY:Number = 0;

 var topY= 0;

but still not work

Comment: Why to 0? Should be `var topY:Number = stage.stageHeight - box.height;

Comment: botY is fine as int. I don't promise this will fix anything but it's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Yes, everything I fine now. Don't know why. Just use your code and did't change anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One bad thing I'm seeing is you are adding an eventListener every frame that the mouse button is down ( I think ).  To not do that, just call start drag once when Mouse Down is true and then stop listening for mouse down. When mouse goes back up, start listening for down again.

```
function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    dragxy = mouseX + "_" + mouseY;
    e.currentTarget.startDrag(false, constrainY);
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
}
function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Neal Davis for more suggestions